# Does Bamboo Charcoal clothes help to improve one's health?

Tags: healthcare, clothing, chlorine

[GreenYarn](http://www.greenyarn.com/benefits.htm) sel a number of products, such as clothing with bamboo charcoal particles are embedded in the fiber.

They claim:

> Health: Bamboo charcoal absorbs chlorine in water and let minerals
>   out, making your skin smooth. Also, the charcoal entirely warms up
>   your body with infrared ray effect, easing stiff shoulders, lumbago,
>   and poor circulation. Bamboo charcoal also absorbs bad odor and toxic
>   substances, and emit negative ion.

Does wearing bamboo charcoal improve your skin or warm your body more than other clothes (or even other charcoals)?

Comment: **Related Question:** http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/is-bamboo-charcoal-safely-edible

Comment: We already have a question about removing odors: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19001/do-charcoal-bags-help-removing-volatile-organic-compounds-vocs - so, can we focus on the health claim here?

Comment: @Oddthinking, Yes, sure, we can focus on the health claim.

Comment: In general, the claims seem suspect based on iffy English alone, but I was surprised to find that the "Infrared rays" claim has some merit. FIR is a thing, and according to this (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4935255/) from the NIH, might have some medicinal effect even in the low doses that this fabric would generate, depending on the accuracy of their claim that activated carbon is a good emitter of NIH.